# python - find coincidences within a certain time windows

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I'm struggling with the following task in python:

I have 4 lists of differet length with timestamps (float values).

```
timestamps
[[0.2, 0.6, 1.5, 4.3],
 [1.1, 1.4, 3.5, 3.6, 7.9],
 [0.1, 0.7, 1.3, 3.7, 12.2, 36.2],
 [1.3, 1.9, 3.8, 4.0, 21.7]]
```

I want to keep only the timestamps that have a coincidence in at least 3 out of 4 lists. By coincidence I mean "having a point inside a window of arbitrary width (let's say 0.2)".

Therefore, in tha above example the only survivors are

```
[[1.5],
 [1.4, 3.6],
 [1.3, 3.7],
 [1.3, 3.8]
```

Because at the time `1.4` I have at least three lists that contain an element in the range `(1.3, 1.5)`, and at the time `3.7` I have at least three lists that contain an element in the range `(3.6, 3.8)`.

I've managed to do this with a moving window, and counting for each window center how many lists contain elements in the range. Obviously, this proves to be extremely time consuming, as my lists are really long and spaced out over a wide range.

Does anyone know any other way (possibly numpy powered or with any other tools) to accomplish this in a quick(ish) way?

Comment: lets assume in the second list you had also the entry 3.7 right after 3.6. What should then be returned?

Comment: With what rule in the result there is no  `[1.1, 1.3, 1.3]`, the length or repetition?

Comment: Yeah it is actually unrelevant, because in my original data I am sure that points in the same list are spaced at least 5 times the threshold. Therefore any solution is accepted